# Validation of type=check in backend on required

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-10.x

How can you validate a checkbox field that it has to be a required field? Following code doesn't work in TYPO3 V10.4.12:

```
'teaching_languages' => [
    'label' => 'teaching_languages',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'check',
        'items' => [
            ['de','1'],
            ['en','2'],
            ['it','3'],
            ['fr','4'],
        ],
        'cols' => 'inline',
        'eval' => 'required'
    ],
],
```

Is there an easy way to achive it or is this a bug? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to check for at least one checked checkbox. That's not possible with `'type' => 'check'`.

I'd suggest to switch to `'type' => 'select'` with render type `'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide'` or `'renderType' => 'selectCheckBox'`.

There you can set `minitems` to 1 to require at least one selection.

See the documentation for details:

- [selectMultipleSideBySide](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select/MultipleSideBySide/Index.html)
- [selectCheckBox](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select/CheckBox/Index.html)

Comment: Thanks Peter Kraume for your hint. I tried selectCheckBox with TYPO3 V10.4.12 which didn't work! So I found this https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83457 that gave me the information to use at minimum V10.4.13. After I update my local TYPO3 Version it works with selectCheckBox and minitems=1.